# API App Not Updating Content

Tags: heroku, caching

I have a simple Node.js JSON API app using free dynos in Heroku, that includes a current timestamp along with other data in its response. When I request the Heroku API URL (below), though, it does not update either the data or the timestamp on each request; it only seems to update every hour or so.

https://theralert.herokuapp.com/

I've been careful that my browser is not caching anything. When I run this app locally it updates as expected on every request. The docs say caching is not on by default.

I clearly don't understand something about how these containers and the Heroku dyno lifecycle work. I'm grateful for any insight or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Not a caching issue, but an issue of both upstream data not changing as expected, and timestamps being recorded at the wrong point in the lifecycle. Sigh. Moving on.